# Blocking Javascript: Firebase .set() is blocking / freezing web pages

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I noticed that my web pages are freezing a little bit because of these lines of JavaScript which send data to firebase.

```
<script src="js/firebase-v2.4.2.js"></script>
<script>
    var fb = new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/');
    fb.child('aaa').set(aaa);
    fb.child('bbb').set(bbb);
    fb.child('ccc').set(ccc);
</script>
```

Is there a way to prevent this somehow and make it run in the background?

I'm thinking of using a web worker but that would be a long path.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I've seen such performance problems, which are unlikely because the writing to the database happens asynchronously. Can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the freezing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built a library that puts Firebase into a web worker and automatically bridges calls from the main page: https://github.com/pkaminski/fireworker.  There are some non-trivial limitations -- and there's no guarantee that transmitting data to the worker won't cause hiccups itself -- but you can give it a try.